# Combinatorial proof using list counting

Tags: combinatorial-proofs

I'm having a lot of trouble coming up with the situation/question for a combinatorial proof that asks to prove
$$2^0 + 2^1 + \dotsb + 2^{n−1} = 2^n − 1$$

Using list counting.
The question I came up with for the right hand side is: what is the number of lists length $n$ you can form with $2$ inputs, excluding the list where all the inputs are $2$.

Comment: "*...you can form with 2 inputs, ...all the inputs are 2*" (*implying that $2$ is one of the possible inputs*)  You will find that it is more common to begin numbering things from zero rather than begin numbering things from one.  If you have two inputs, they would be $0$ and $1$ rather than $1$ and $2$.  That is not to say that counting from $1$ in scenarios like this is *wrong* per se, just that it is less common.  Keep that in mind as you read answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think about binary strings of length $n$ with at least one $1$ ... & where the first $1$ occurs in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Every list of $n$ $0$'s and $1$'s has $i$ leading $0$'s where $0 \leq i \leq n$. There is $1$ list with $n$ leading $0$'s. And in general there are $2^k$ lists with $n-k$ leading $0$'s. The total number of lists of $n$ $0$'s and $1$'s is $2^n$.